# Compara información de un DataSource en un DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net

Estoy mostrando la información de una tabla en un DataGridView, mediante un metodo Async estoy refrescando la información cada determinado tiempo ( 1 segundo ), mi problema es que cuando el usuario tiene seleccionado un campo al momento de refrescar la nueva información se pierde su selección y esta se posiciona en la primer celda, como podría evitar que esto pasara?

```
private async Task UpdateDataGridView()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();      
        while (true)
        {
            dt = new CatBonosLN().UpdateBonoPorUsuario( this.nameUsuario );

            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = dt;               
            this.gridMovimientosUsuario.DataSource = bs;   

            await Task.Delay(1000); // Se detiene un segundo el while
        }            
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estas seteando nuevamente todo el BindingSource lo que carga nuevamente todos los registros en el GridView, lo ideal seria actualizar únicamente la fila con los nuevos datos de modo que el grid no tenga que redibujarse ya que con ello pierdes la selección, otra opción es guardar en una variable el ultimo registro seleccionado y asignar la selección nuevamente después de ejecutar el método update.

Answer (score 0):

@JessMad, puedes almacenar la variable del Id y hacer algo como esto.

```
DataGridViewRow row =
            dgvPedidos.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == Id);
row.Selected = true;
```

Espero haberte ayudado.